# Table view scrolling all the way down not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I got 3 labels on my view displaying some stuff, a table view below (beginning at screen halfway down) and 
a data retrieval method where I fill up an NSArray for the table view.
Everything works, the problem now is if there are more than a few elements in the array for the table view (more than the screen can display at once) I'm not able to scroll down to the bottom, it's always autoscrolling up again, as if the table view was empty space there (which it is not, I checked of course).

It worked on the previous screen the way I did it, I think the iOS doesn't notice the labels or something similar - it thinks the table view has the whole screen for itself. I tried resizing the table view in the xib to let it end just before the screen ends but the table view occupies all screen beginning from where it started. I also tried to

```
initWithFrame:CGRectMake...
```

But this did not work as well. Any ideas whats going on here? I'd be really glad about some help, thanks guys!

EDIT:

.h file

```
@interface ZProjekt : UIViewController     <RetailHeaderTabSource, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate , UITableViewDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
{
NSString *messageBody;
NSString *subjectBody;
NSMutableArray *fieldsInTable;
int fieldscounter;
}

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *tableNamed;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *objectsInTable;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *DetailModal;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mboSyncGroup;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@end
```

here is the code of the tableview .m file

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
// Return the number of sections
return 1;
} 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return fieldscounter;
 }    
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath     *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
cell.textLabel.text = fieldsInTable[indexPath.row];
[Constants updateLabelValues:cell.textLabel withKey:k_IPhone_DetailCell_HeaderLabel];
return cell;
}
```

Comment: are you using autolayout or autoresizemasks?

Comment: No I don't think so, I did not set it up on purpose so if it's not a default setting, it's off.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one :

```
[tableView setContentOffset:CGPointMake(tableView.frame.size.width, tableView.frame.size.height) animated:NO];
```

or

on the TableViewController->Table View check the clip Subviews n Autoresize Subviews.

Also,
make sure the total rows are the same with the total contents in the tableView which is 3

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 3;
}
```

Problem Found ! The problem is, the tableview doesn't know which table you are scrolling either the last one or the previous one. You need to re-assign the value to the NSMutableArray. You need to store the content of the array in the table1 into array or dictionary and you need to reassign in the CellForRowIndexPath. I had the same problem like this.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

if (tableView != table2.tblView) {
        fieldsInTable = table1.fieldsInTable;
    }
    else
    {
        fieldsInTable = table2.fieldsInTable;
    }


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
 }
cell.textLabel.text = fieldsInTable[indexPath.row];
[Constants updateLabelValues:cell.textLabel withKey:k_IPhone_DetailCell_HeaderLabel];
return cell;

}
```

Comment: Mhh the contentOffset did not work unfortunately, and why is the numberOfRowsInSection 3? Isn't it variable depending on how many objects I got in my array?

Comment: yap, you are right, but you can go through your array under that method and make sure the total count is 3.

Comment: Oh and you should know - this screen appears if you hit a cell in the previous table view (it's a detail table view basically). So the objects in the array can be 1-100, it's not always 3!

Comment: First change this :
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
return [fieldsInTable count];
}

Comment: Both return the same value. But fine I did, but of course that does not change anything.

Comment: mho sorry I can't follow, I only have one table on this screen?

Comment: set the Header on the Storyboard->Table View -> Show the Size Inspector -> Header